# Как подобрать селектор, чтобы он со страницы извлекал ссылки одного домена?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Используется: WebDriver, С#

Код:

```
link = browser1.FindElements(By.CssSelector(a[href*=ibm])).ToList();
```

Извлекаем ссылки и получаем ссылки двух категорий. см. скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А требуется, чтобы извлекались ссылки "Категория 1"
Пробовал изменить селектор на `a[href*=ibm.com]`, а также другие интерпретации.

В результате `CssSelector` перестаёт работать.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно подобрать `CssSelector`, что извлекались ссылки необходимого домена?

Answer (score 1):

Много возможно вариантов. Как насчет проверять, что ссылка *заканчивается* на `?lnk=flg`:

```
a[href$="?lnk=flg"]
```

`$=` здесь значит "заканчивается на".

Еще вариант, проверять, что *начинается* на `http://www.ibm.com`:

```
a[href^="http://www.ibm.com"]
```

И тот, и другой варианты мне не сильно по душе, но возможно они окажутся практичными и подходящими для Вашей ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, нужен xpath вроде такого:

```
//a[contains(@href,'ibm.com')]
```